# How do I calculate the number of combinations, where a minimum number of elements must be different?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have 54 names.

I would like to know how many unique combinations of 6 names I can create, where at least 2 of the names are different from those in every other combination?

My maths is extremely rusty but I understand how to calculate the number of unique combinations.

I also understand how to calculate the number of unique combinations, where 1 name (or x names) must be include in every combination.

I'm not at all sure how to go about solving this problem, except by brute-force for small numbers of names.

An example based on 7 choose 3 would be 123,145,167,246,257,347,356.  No combination contains 2 of the same numbers.

Comment: It is difficult to discern what you are asking.  Could you perhaps give an example of what the answer would be with, say, three names?

Comment: Does this fall within the gamut of the [self-study](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) tag? I am unsure - could you please check?

Comment: @Glen_b Unfortunately, I am past the studying age. This is part of a game concept I am looking at with a friend.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity. An example based on 7 choose 3 would be 123,145,167,246,257,347,356.

Comment: Please edit this information into your question. I'm glad you cleared that up - I had misinterpreted what you meant and my approach is simply wrong. I have deleted my answer; it was useless.

Comment: @whuber I edited the question to provide a simple example, based on 7 choose 3 where no combinations contain 2 of the same numbers.

Comment: I do not understand your example, Clair. For instance, why aren't 124 or 245 within your list? As a matter of terminology, a "combination" is just another name for "subset"; there are 21 unique combinations of three elements out of seven. Are you perhaps asking to find a largest set of combinations, no two of which have more than one element in common?

Comment: @whuber 124 and 245 aren't contained in the list as they contain 2 or more of the same number - in this case 2 & 4 repeated. In the 7 choose 3 example the constraint is that no combination contains 2 or more of the same numbers.